# Reversed source string into destination

Tags: c

I am trying to reverse a string and write the reversed string into a destination. I have to use the same basic structure and cannot figure out what it wrong with my reverse function.

```
void reverse(const char source[], char destination[]) {

if(source = 0){
    return;
}
else
{
    reverse(source+1, destination);
    destination[strlen(source)-1]=source;
}

}

void testingReverse() {
    const char *sources[] = {
    "Welcome to CMPSC 311!",
    "abcdef",
    "_ ab  cd  ef *"
};
    const char *expected[] = {
    "!113 CSPMC ot emocleW",
    "fedcba",
    "* fe  dc  ba _"
};
    char destination[50];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        printf("source: \"%s\"\n", sources[i]);
        memset(destination, 'x', 49);
        destination[49] = 0;
        reverse(sources[i], destination);
        printf("destination: \"%.49s\"\n", destination);
        if (strcmp(destination, expected[i]) == 0) {
            printf("----pass----\n");
        }
        else {
            printf("----fail----\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Following is the result I am getting right now.

```
Testing reverse:

source: "Welcome to CMPSC 311!"

Segmentation fault: 11
```

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] that shows how you call this function?

Comment: Edited with the function call.

Comment: You don't have compiler warnings turned on -- do you? gcc/clang add `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`, for VS add `/W3` -- and do not accept code until it compiles without warning. `source = 0` looks funny, hmm... `"suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value"` -- is that what you intend? `destination[strlen(source)-1]=source;` -- `"assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast"` -- looking bad...

Comment: This line: `if(source = 0){` ***assigns*** `0` to `source`.  You mean to ***compare*** `source` and `0` : `if(source == 0){`

Comment: 50 makes more sense than 49 in `"destination: \"%.49s\"\n"`.  With errant code that filled `destination`, it would be useful to print the 50th `char`.  Of course if the null character is missing, `strcmp(destination, expected[i])` is bad.  Suggest `strncmp(destination, expected[i], 50)`.

Comment: You can also use `-pedantic-errors` to completely error out on non-ansi compliant code. And `-Werror` will upgrade warnings to errors... Never include them in your final product though, they can cause a real headache for maintaining code as new compilers get released.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void reverse(const char *source ,  char *destination) 
{
int i=0;
int length=0;

length=strlen(source);

if(!length) return;

strcpy( destination , source);

   while(source[i])
   { 
       printf("\n%c",source[i]);
       destination[length-(1+i)]=source[i];
       printf("\n=====> %s",destination);
       i++;
   }

printf("\n%s", destination);

}

int main()
{
   char string[99];
   char destination[99];

    strcpy( string, "abcdefghijklmnop");
    reverse(string, destination);
    }
```

Comment: Code fails corner case: `reverse("",  destination)` leaves `destination` unassigned.  Removing the unneeded `if(!length) return;` code will fix.

Answer (score 1):

You may be wildly over complicating reversing a string. All you need to know is the length of the source string (and that it will fit in the destination) and then at it's most basic form you can reverse source into dest with a simple `for` loop using indexes, e.g.

```
void reverse (char *dst, const char *src)
{
    size_t i, j = strlen(src);

    for (i = 0; src[i]; i++)        /* loop over each char in src */
        dst[i] = src[--j];          /*  decrement j, reverse copy to dst */

    dst[i] = src[i];                /* nul-terminate dst */
}
```

(**note:** the order of `src` and `dst` parameters are switched to be consistent with the other string functions such as `strcpy`, etc..)

Now this is far from complete. You want/need additional validations to insure your parameters are valid and that the reversed source string will fit in the destination buffer provided. Adding the validations, you could do something like the following to make things a bit more robust, e.g.

```
#define MAXC 1024

void reverse (char *dst, const char *src)
{
    size_t i, j;

    /* validate src and dest not NULL */
    if (src == NULL || dst == NULL) {
        fputs ("error: NULL paraemter passed.\n", stderr);
        return;
    }

    j = strlen(src);                /* get index of last char in src */

    if (j >= MAXC) { /* validate reversed src fits in dst */
        fputs ("error: src exceeds MAXC - 1.\n", stderr);
        *dst = 0;   /* set dst to empty-string */
        return;
    }

    for (i = 0; src[i]; i++)        /* loop over each char in src */
        dst[i] = src[--j];          /* decrement j, reverse copy to dst */

    dst[i] = src[i];                /* nul-terminate dst */
}
```

Adding the needed `#include` files and a short example program that will reverse the string provided as the 1st argument to the program (or reversing `"Welcome to CMPSC 311!"` by default if no argument is provided), you could do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXC 1024
...
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *s = argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "Welcome to CMPSC 311!",
        rev[MAXC];

    reverse (rev, s);

    printf ("original: %s\nreversed: %s\n", s, rev);
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/reverse
original: Welcome to CMPSC 311!
reversed: !113 CSPMC ot emocleW
```

Or, passing a string as input to the program:

```
$ ./bin/reverse "My dog has fleas and my cat has none."
original: My dog has fleas and my cat has none.
reversed: .enon sah tac ym dna saelf sah god yM
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Hmm, the empty string need not be an error, but it is just very boring to reverse. Interesting variation of the `j` decrement. Thanks.

Comment: Agreed, removing `- 1` and `j--` from `for` loop declaration and using `dst[i] = src[--j];` looks cleaner and there is no remembering to subtract one from `strlen`.

Comment: @chux, tweaked. 4-eyes always better than 2 -- and glasses don't count.

Comment: @chux I like it, `jge` instead of `add + jgt`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will give you inspiration

```
void reverse(char *str) { 
    if (*str) { 
       reverse(str+1); 
       printf("%c", *str); 
    } 
}
```

You could also look into strrev(arr);

https://www.programmingsimplified.com/c-program-reverse-string